# MYSQL Postcode lookup

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL table with the following fields postcode, town, county. Based on the postcode number I want to do a lookup to get the closest matching town and county.

The postcodes are essentially postcode districts, so for example:

AL1 = Saint Albans, Hertfordshire
AL10 = Hatfield, Hertfordshire

In the example above lets say I'm querying AL10 I want to retrieve the closest match, so in this case it would be AL10 = Hatfield, Hertfordshire. But if AL10 didn't exist I want to retrieve AL1.

I have got around this by first querying for a match on AL10 then if that failed AL1, then if that failed AL.

But this seems like a very inefficient way to achieve this seeing as I'm querying the table potentially 3 times. Is there a better and more efficient way to achieve the same goal?

Comment: Is this really a good idea? The higher numbered postcodes tend to be the outlying parts of a postcode area. Truncating them will return a postcode district close to the centre of the area which could be 30 miles away.

Comment: Feasibility not withstanding, this might be a job for a stored procedure.

Comment: [this link](http://www.doogal.co.uk/UKPostcodes.php) has a downloadable CSV file containing all of the postcodes in the UK.  (I'm assuming that's where you're looking for, I'm not sure).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Accuracy is not paramount here, where as speed is. instead, where a more accurate match can be done I would like to make that match otherwise take the closest match from there